# SQL join with different "where" clause than the rest of the query?

Tags: sql

```
    SELECT `bid_amount`,`valid_until`, min('bid_amount') as `lowest_bid`
    `cf1`.`country_name` AS `country_from`, `rq`.`city_from`,
    `cf2`.`country_name` AS `country_to`, `rq`.`city_to`,
    `sub_cat`.`sub_cat_name`,
    `cat`.`cat_name`
    FROM `bids`
    JOIN `request_quote` `rq` ON `bids`.`bid_for` = `rq`.`quoteid`
    JOIN `countries` `cf1` ON `rq`.`country_from` = `cf1`.`country_id`
    JOIN `countries` `cf2` ON `rq`.`country_to` = `cf2`.`country_id`
    LEFT JOIN `cat` ON `rq`.`cat` = `cat`.`cat_id`
    LEFT JOIN `sub_cat` ON `rq`.`sub_cat` = `sub_cat`.`sub_cat_id`
    WHERE `bids`.`bid_by` = $bidderId GROUP BY `bids`.`bid_amount`
```

So I am working on this auction kind of site. What I need to return is all bids by particular user, and in addition to that some extra information about every bid.

One piece of information that I want is the lowest bid on every item.
So here is the bids table. 'bid_for` references the item for which the bid is. So I want to get that 'min(bid_amount)' that is referenced by "where bid_for = x". But as you see in the last line I already have WHERE clause that references it by user id.

So in short, is there anyway to select one (or more) piece of information that is referenced by different "where" clause than the rest of the query? (if that makes sense)

```
+--------+--------+---------+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| bid_id | bid_by | bid_for | bid_amount | pickup_date | delivery_date | valid_until |
+--------+--------+---------+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
|      1 |     24 |       2 |      19.99 | 2013-06-01  | 2013-06-01    | 2013-06-01  |
|      2 |     27 |       2 |      25.00 | 2013-06-01  | 2013-06-01    | 2013-06-01  |
+--------+--------+---------+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Use AND operator? i.e. `WHERE blah = blah AND blah = blah`

Comment: @adaam Sorry I probably didn't express myself well enough. This min value needs to be referenced by ONLY bid_for (as in get the lowest bid for this item from all users, and not just me)

Comment: What are you developing in apart from SQL (PHP, .NET?)

Comment: Can you supply some sample data and desired results?  Possibly you'll need to use a correlated subquery if different where criteria is really needed.

Comment: PHP(codeigniter).. If possible though Id like to accomplish this in SQL alone. Because I suspect that otherwise I need to run an extra query for each bid? Or is running multiple queries not such a bad thing as I believe?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an inner select statement:

```
SELECT `bid_amount`,`valid_until`, (SELECT min('bid_amount') FROM 'bids') as `lowest_bid`
`cf1`.`country_name` AS `country_from`, `rq`.`city_from`,
`cf2`.`country_name` AS `country_to`, `rq`.`city_to`,
`sub_cat`.`sub_cat_name`,
`cat`.`cat_name`
FROM `bids`
JOIN `request_quote` `rq` ON `bids`.`bid_for` = `rq`.`quoteid`
JOIN `countries` `cf1` ON `rq`.`country_from` = `cf1`.`country_id`
JOIN `countries` `cf2` ON `rq`.`country_to` = `cf2`.`country_id`
LEFT JOIN `cat` ON `rq`.`cat` = `cat`.`cat_id`
LEFT JOIN `sub_cat` ON `rq`.`sub_cat` = `sub_cat`.`sub_cat_id`
WHERE `bids`.`bid_by` = $bidderId GROUP BY `bids`.`bid_amount`
```

Comment: Cool this works as well. I suppose I'll accept your answer, since accepting my own wouldn't look good. But for anyone looking at this, know that both answers does the job! So probably just a preference of syntax... :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok came up with solution myself. I aliased the `bids` table, and joined it to the un-aliased `bids` table. Like so:

```
SELECT `bids`.`bid_amount`,`bids`.`valid_until`,
    min(`min`.`bid_amount`) AS `lowest_bid`,
    `cf1`.`country_name` AS `country_from`, `rq`.`city_from`,
    `cf2`.`country_name` AS `country_to`, `rq`.`city_to`,
    `sub_cat`.`sub_cat_name`,
    `cat`.`cat_name`
    FROM `bids`
    JOIN `request_quote` `rq` ON `bids`.`bid_for` = `rq`.`quoteid`
    JOIN `bids` `min` ON `min`.`bid_for` = `rq`.`quoteid`
    JOIN `countries` `cf1` ON `rq`.`country_from` = `cf1`.`country_id`
    JOIN `countries` `cf2` ON `rq`.`country_to` = `cf2`.`country_id`
    LEFT JOIN `cat` ON `rq`.`cat` = `cat`.`cat_id`
    LEFT JOIN `sub_cat` ON `rq`.`sub_cat` = `sub_cat`.`sub_cat_id`
    WHERE `bids`.`bid_by` = $bidderId GROUP BY `bids`.`bid_for`
```

Didn't even know you could join same table onto same table. But here you go, live and learn :)